# Making Destroyer (UnityC#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I making simple runner game.

I want do have some block over which player which jump.

I make a prefab and quad.

Attached Spawn script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject[] obj;
    public float spawnMin = 1f;
    public float spawnMax = 1f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        Spawn();
    }

    void Spawn()
    {
        Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Invoke("Spawn", Random.Range(spawnMin, spawnMax)); 
    }
}
```

Also I attached Destroyer script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
            return;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.transform.parent)
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);
        }

        else
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

But when player enter this object nothing happens.

Screen of my Quad:

[image: Quad]

Where is my mistake?

Comment: How does a player enter your object? Can you show the code where you actually call - yeah, which of the scripts actually?

Comment: When player enter block ,I call Destroyer script. @HimBromBeere

Comment: The question was HOW you call that script. Show the relevant code

Comment: Make sure you have a rigidbody2d attached to one of the gameobjects

Comment: Yes, I have rigidbody@Savlon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [OnTriggerEnter2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html). If your collider not ticked isTrigger field, you can use [OnCollisionEnter2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html).

And also if your object has Normal (3D) collider you need to use 3D versions of them.

[OnTriggerEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) or [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html).

And also you should read [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html).

**UPDATE**

After discussion and looking your project problem is your character doesnt hit the destroyer object's collider. It moves with your main camera. (Destroyer object is child object of camera). Because of that when you take your destroyer from camera's child object it works.

Comment: In BoxCollider I set IsTrigger

Comment: Is your collider BoxCollider or BoxCollider2D?

Comment: Does your main object has rigidbody2d?

Comment: Yes, objects has rigidbody2d

Comment: @BarışÇırıka , i usually encourage new programmers to use **Debug.Log** everywhere, such as `Debug.Log(gameObject.name);`  (a) it's a a huge waste of your time when you try to help someone and they have the "scripts on the wrong thing", (b) the world must unit test!  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow i am totaly agree with you. I wrote generic problems and solutions.

Comment: I fix my problem. My block was in Main Camera. When I take it from it, it works.

Comment: Can I make same , when my object is in Main Camera?

Comment: I think it is not cause a problem. But you need to add more info to understand situation

Comment: Add screen of my Destroyer (quad)

Comment: Does your character has rigidbody2d? And also if your block doesn't need to affect by physics you can remove rigidbody2d.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105907/discussion-between---and-baris-cirika).

Comment: After discussion and looking your project problem is your character doesnt hit the festroyer object's collider. It moves with your main camera. (Destroyer object is child object of camera). Because of that when you take your destroyer from camera's child object it works.

Comment: Okay, how I can make spawning of destoyer objects when it not in MainCamera?

Comment: Simply add destroyer script in dogs. If you want dogs destroy, you can check x position is far from character(Back of the character maybe -x) then it can call Destroy(). (Simply you can do this algorithm in Update() method.),  and check if character collide with it. (So it is game over.). And also i strongly recommend that dont destroy dogs, change transfrom it to forward of your charecter. Destroy and instantiate operations damage performance. (You can look at [Object Pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling)).

Answer (score 0):

Any child object in the heirarchy inherits it's parents movement. So if the collider is on a child object of the camera, it will move when the camera moves.