# Make object that destroy player

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I writing simple game on Unity (C#)

I have player and want to make the destroyer, that will destroy player.

I create prefab of destroyer. And next, I create Quad.

I have spawn script:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnScript : MonoBehaviour {


    public GameObject[] obj;
    public float spawnMin = 1f;
    public float spawnMax = 2f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


        Spawn();


    }

    void Spawn()

    {
        Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Invoke("Spawn", Random.Range(spawnMin, spawnMax)); 

    }
}
```

Also I write DestroyerScript:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
            return;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.transform.parent)
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);
        }

        else
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

My destroyer spawning, but when player get it, I don't have Game Over screen.

[image: Passing]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making Destroyer (UnityC#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888872/making-destroyer-unityc)

Answer (score 0):

Add **rigid body** to both player and "player destroyer" and then set `onTriggerEnter` on your player destroyer like so:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

For some fine tuning, you can do some checks if the **other** object is in fact the Destroyer (you can compare the **tag** or something, I won't go into too much detail now).

EDIT: Uncheck "isTrigger" on your BoxColliders and try this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
         Destroy(col.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: OnTriggerEnter or OnTriggerEnter2D?

Comment: Well I guess your game is 3D right? If it is, use regular OnTriggerEnter. Don't forget to set rigid body on BOTH objects first.

Comment: if it's 2D game, use 2D trigger enter.

Comment: Did you add 2D rigid body?

Comment: Yes, on player and destroyer

Comment: Try with my edit above ^ although I don't understand why onTriggerEnter2D doesn't work if you had set up everything correctly.

Comment: Your problem is strange. But you have rigidbody2d and box collider2d so you need to add 2d versions of them (Trigger or Collision).

Comment: Exactly, use everything for 2D, I thought I was clear on that.

Comment: (He asked same question). After discussion and looking your project problem is your character doesnt hit the destroyer object's collider. It moves with your main camera. (Destroyer object is child object of camera). Because of that when you take your destroyer from camera's child object it works.